# How can I get typeahead.js to play nicely with jquery.validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, typeahead.js

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website that uses jQuery validation (`jquery.validate.js` in the MVC project template). I'm trying to use `typeahead.js` to implement type-ahead functionality on one of the input fields in a form. (The form happens to be inside a bootstrap modal).

Because submitting the form will make an AJAX request, the form submit event is trapped like so:

```
$form.on("submit", function (e) {

    if (!$form.valid()) {
        return false;
    }

    ... do stuff ...
```

Note that the first thing that happens here is that the form is checked for any validation errors, as detected by the jQuery validation library.

If I **don't** use `typeahead`, then everything is fine. I can enter values into my form and submit it, and all is well.

However, as soon as I do the following to add type-ahead functionality to my input:

```
$("#myInput").typeahead({
    minLength: 1,
    highlight: true
},
{
    source: mySource
});
```

...then I can no longer submit the form. My form is considered to be *not* valid: `$form.valid()` returns `false`.

I think the `typeahead.js` library is adding some extra elements (including a hidden input) to the form, and this is confusing the `jquery.validate.js` library.

Using Chrome F12, it seems there's an input there that looks like a copy of the original input, and sadly that copy appears to have been duplicated such that it also has copies of all the jQuery-validation attributes.

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work (placed immediately after the call to `typeahead()`:

```
$("input.tt-hint").removeAttr("data-val data-val-required data-val-maxlength data-val-maxlength-max");
```

Comment: In my case I also had to add removeClass("required")

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the extra input has the `tt-hint` class on it so you could set up validate to ignore inputs with that class.

```
$form.validate({
    ignore: ':hidden, .tt-hint'
});
```

Comment: That fixed one problem and caused another. I can submit the form, but now if I try to submit the form where all the inputs are blank (say), then the  validation messages are shown (good), but don't disappear when I enter some text (bad).

Comment: Alternatively, it seems you could add hint: false to your typeahead options.  Not sure if that will make a difference but worth a try